# Puppeteer & Google Chrome headless: influence of CSS @media on rendered PDF

Tags: javascript, css, pdf-generation, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am using Puppeteer to render PDF out of HTML pages.

I specify media type to be 'screen' before rendering to PDF:

```
await page.emulateMedia('screen');
```

Let's assume I have an HTML page in which the `<body>` element has white background.

Under these conditions, am I right in expecting that styling of this kind:

```
@media screen {
  body {
    background: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

will make Puppeteer render a PDF where the  element will have the background coloured `#ff0000`?

I am asking because it does not work on my machine, and I want to eliminate any known issues or other problems.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your assumption, but make sure that the `printBackground` option in [`page.pdf()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions) is set to `true` before attempting to print.

Otherwise, the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) colors and graphics will not be printed.

```
await page.emulateMedia('screen');

await page.pdf({
  path: 'example.pdf',
  printBackground: true,
});
```